# MobX create and reference new Observables based on values inside established Observables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, mobx, mobx-react

In one of the features of my application, I'm syncing with Firebase to get a list of active events. The primary result of this means that the observable will be set repeatedly in real time. This is great, but it has led to some MobX troubles. To demonstrate, take a look at the relevant store:

```
import { observable, computed, autorun, extendObservable, reaction } from "mobx";
import { subscribe } from "./firebase";


class HomeStore {


    @observable activeEvents = {};

    @observable currentEvents = [];

    constructor() {
        console.log(this);
        // subscribe( root => root.ref("meta/activeEvents"), this.activeEvents, "object" );
        setTimeout(() => this.currentEvents["RE-VRC-16-1274"] = true, 100);
        reaction(
            () => Object.keys(this.currentEvents),
            events =>
                events.map( event =>
                    this.currentEvents[event] === true ?
                    subscribe( root => root.ref(`events/${event}`), this.currentEvents[event], "object") :
                    null
                )
            );


    }

}

export default new HomeStore();
```

Here, the `subscribe` function will bind a specific part of my database to the specified observable (the `setTimeout` does essentially the same thing). What I am trying to achieve is such:

1. The state is empty, as specified by the original store state
2. My `subscribe()` function changes the values of children of `this.currentEvents`, which triggers a reaction to create new observables, and subscribe them to their appropriate path in the database
3. As these observables are changed by `subscribe()`, the `render()` function of my React Component changes. See below for that source

   ```
   import { h, Component } from 'preact';
   import { List, ListItem, Icon } from 'preact-mdl';
   import { observer } from "mobx-observer";

   import { icon, center } from "../style";

   import HomeStore from "../stores/home";

   @observer
   export default class EventList extends Component {

   constructor() {
       super();
       this.store = HomeStore;
   }

   render() {
           console.log("EventList Renders", Object.assign({}, this.store.events));
           return (
               <List>
                       {Object.keys(this.store.currentEvents).map( event =>
                           <ListItem two-line>
                               <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                   <Icon icon="event" class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar" style={icon.avatar}></Icon>
                                   <span>{ this.store.currentEvents[event].name ? this.store.currentEvents[event].name : "Loading..." }</span>
                                   <span class="mdl-list__item-sub-title">{ event }</span>
                               </span>
                           </ListItem>
                       )
                   }
               </List>
           );
       }
   }
   ```

This seems like it should be pretty easy to do, but I am struggling. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better approach? Any advice is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't read the rest of the question, but this won't fly: `reaction(() => Object.keys(this.currentEvents)`. Mobx cannot track the addition of keys to an object, so for dynamically keyed data structures use the built-in maps from mobx, e.g.: `activeEvents = observable.map()`